# Python Subprocess Loop runs Twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, ghostscript

So, I created a Python script to batch convert PDF files using Ghostscript. Ideally it should work, but I am not sure why it isn't working. For now, it is going through the input PDF files twice and when it runs the second time, it overwrites the output files.

Here's the script.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import subprocess

try:
   os.mkdir('compressed')
except FileExistsError:
   pass   

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
   for file in files:
      if file.endswith(".pdf"):
         filename = os.path.join(root, file)
         arg1= '-sOutputFile=' + './compressed/' + file
         print ("compressing:", file )
         p = subprocess.Popen(['gs', '-sDEVICE=pdfwrite', '-dCompatibilityLevel=1.4', '-dPDFSETTINGS=/screen', '-dNOPAUSE', '-dBATCH',  '-dQUIET', str(arg1), filename], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).wait()
```

Here's the ouput.

[image]

I am missing what did I do wrong.

Comment: `file` is just the name of the file. You have several files called the same in different directories

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I only have those 6 files in that folder.

Comment: but `compressed` is scanned too since it's in `.` !!

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file` is just the name of the file. You have several files called the same in different directories. Don't forget that `os.walk` recurses in subdirectories by default.

So you have to save the converted files in a directory or name which depends on `root`.

*and put the output directory outside the current directory as `os.walk` will scan it*

For instance, for flat output replace:

```
arg1= '-sOutputFile=' + './compressed/' + file
```

by

```
arg1= '-sOutputFile=' + '/somewhere/else/compressed/' + root.strip(".").replace(os.sep,"_")+"_"+file
```

The expression

```
root.strip(".").replace(os.sep,"_")
```

should create a "flat" version of `root` tree without current directory (no dot) and path separators converted to underscores, plus one final underscore. That's one option that would work.

An alternate version that won't scan `./compressed` or any other subdirectory (maybe more what you're looking for) would be using `os.listdir` instead (no recursion)

```
root = "."
for file in os.listdir(root):
  if file.endswith(".pdf"):
     filename = os.path.join(root, file)
     arg1= '-sOutputFile=' + './compressed/' + file
     print ("compressing:", file )
```

Or `os.scandir`

```
root = "."
for entry in os.scandir(root):
  file = entry.name
  if file.endswith(".pdf"):
     filename = os.path.join(root, file)
     arg1= '-sOutputFile=' + './compressed/' + file
     print ("compressing:", file )
```

Comment: Thanks for `os.listdir(root)` that's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: If you don't care about the order, `os.scandir(root)` is generally faster, but the difference will be tiny if you just have a few files.

Comment: `scandir` is definitely a lot faster specially on windows, true, but in that above case it's the same thing as there are no other operations such as `os.getmtime()` or `stat` calls.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that os.walk will also retrieve that contents in "compressed" directory. This is because the files will be compressed and created before os.walk list files in that directory. If you add `print(os.path.join(root, file))` to your for-loop you will notice that.

Bellow is a snippet that works since the files retrieved are only the ones in the current directory.

```py
import os

os.makedirs("compressed", exist_ok=True)

for file in os.listdir("."):
    if not os.path.isfile(file):
        continue
    if not file.endswith(".pdf"):
        continue
    print(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

`os.walk` will by definition enter into subdirectories, so you are compressing the files in the `compressed` subdirectory a second time.

Probably you simply want

```
for file in os.scandir("."):
   ...
```

As an aside, you almost certainly want to avoid `Popen` in favor of `subprocess.run()` or one of its legacy variations.

Answer (score 0):

On the first iteration of
`for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".")`
you find the files in the current directory, then you compress them into the
`./compressed/*.pdf` path.

After that the second iteration of the outer loop will find the already compressed files in the subdirectory.

Easiest fix is to move the output directory outside of the input directory (or create an `input` directory next to the `compressed` dir, and read the files from there instead of `.`)